# Using custom SMTP server with Laravel / swiftmailer fails, same settings work in Thunderbird

Tags: php, laravel, email, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send an email using SwiftMailer (which is what Laravel uses by default):

```
    $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.my-server.com', 465, "tls"))
        ->setAuthMode('PLAIN')
        ->setUsername('my-username')
        ->setPassword('my-password');
    $mailer    = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

    $message = (new Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'))
        ->setFrom(['address@my-domain.com' => 'My Name'])
        ->setTo(['my-gmail-address@gmail.com'])
        ->setBody('Here is the message itself');

    $mailer->send($message);

    echo "\nMail sent! \n\n";
```

And running this gives me:

> Expected response code 220 but got an empty response

Using the same settings in Thunderbird (an email client) works:

[image: Thunderbird settings window, showing that it works]

I'm able to send emails with these settings in Thunderbird. (from the same system I'm attempting to use swiftmailer)

So how can I debug this? Is there some default setting that I need to change in swiftmailer to make this work? Is there some way I can get more debug information?

My SMTP server doesn't even log an authentication attempt. It's like swiftmailer isn't even trying to connect to my smtp server!

UPDATE: I tried using `Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin` to get more debugging info, but it was no help:

> ++ Starting Swift_SmtpTransport
>
> !! Expected response code 220 but got an empty response (code: 0)

Comment: Why are you manually calling the Swift Mailer? You should use the Mail facade that laravel provides

Comment: yes, I know.... I just called the swiftmailer directly so I could debug why it's not working. Using the Mail facade (setting all the correct values in mail.php) causes the same error.

Comment: Just tried your code with mailtrap.io and it works fine, check that your gmail account accepts mail from unsecure sources

Comment: Since Laravel uses the swiftmailer, if I can't get it to send using just swiftmailer, it definitely won't work using Laravel's Mail facade.

Comment: @CaddyDZ I'm not using a Gmail smtp server, it's a private smtp server

Comment: But you're sending **to** gmail and it returns that code `220` for unsecure sources to prevent spam

Comment: Also check that your app is running under `https`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198851/discussion-between-caddy-dz-and-skeets).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TLDR; use `ssl` instead of `tls` when using a port that forces `ssl/tls`. Swiftmailer's "tls" actually isn't `tls`, it's `starttls`.

It seems that swiftmailer's "tls" encryption option is mislabeled! My server only accepts `ssl/tls` on port 465, and I was able to connect to it over Thunderbird, but swiftmailer was unable to.

When I switched to port 587, which only supports `starttls` on my server, it worked, even though the encryption is set to `tls` (which should NOT be the same as `starttls`).

Looking at the source files confirmed my suspicion:

```
if ($this->params['tls']) {
    try {
        $this->executeCommand("STARTTLS\r\n", [220]);
            ...
```

when it's set to `tls`, it actually means `starttls`. :P

So if you want to use `ssl/tls`, do not use the swiftmailer encryption option "tls"

When I changed the encryption to `ssl`, it worked on the port that enforced `ssl/tls`. So the answer is to use `ssl`.

EDIT: I went to open an issue on the swiftmail github, but [the issue was already there in "open" status](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/545). So I wasn't the only one to be bitten by this.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I've also gone through it and this worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not sure which version this applies to, but FYI - this did not work for me in Laravel 6.18.14. With MAIL_PORT=587 and MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl I get the following 'Connection could not be established with host smtp-relay.gmail.com' and 'SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number'. However, when I use MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls the connection works, but fails on authentication :(

Comment: I don't know about using gmail, this was using a private STMP server. [In appears that gmail supports TLS and STARTTLS](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en&visit_id=637278691726229859-767496123&rd=3) on that port, so yeah, either `ssl` or `tls` should be fine from the Laravel side (assuming that documentation page I linked to is correct). This Q/A was mostly about SMTP servers that enforce TLS (don't allow STARTTLS)

Comment: I switched away from using Gmail to my private SMTP server when something in gmail changed without warning and caused emails from my Laravel application to completely stop working.